Real Time resnet prediction
I trained a resnet50 model on number hand signs from 0 to 5, and Im trying to deploy it to predict real time classes via the laptop's webcam.
although the model has 98% accuracy and I am pretty sure the error's not occurring because the model was trained badly, the real time values are stuck to 1 or 2 classes of the 5, they always predict number 0 and number 2.
this is the code :
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cv2
import numpy as np
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image  # Import PIL for image conversion

# Define the model architecture and load weights
class ResNet50Modified(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=6):
        super(ResNet50Modified, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)  # Use pretrained=True for better performance
        self.model.fc = nn.Linear(self.model.fc.in_features, num_classes)

    def forward(self, X):
        return self.model(X)

# Load the trained model
model = ResNet50Modified(num_classes=6)
# Load the model's state_dict for CPU
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("resnet50_modified1.pth", map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
model.eval()

# Define transformations to match training preprocessing
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((64, 64)),  # Resize to input size of model
    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert to tensor
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])  # Normalize as per ResNet standards
])

# Labels for the signs
class_names = ['Class_0', 'Class_1', 'Class_2', 'Class_3', 'Class_4', 'Class_5']  # Replace with actual sign names

# Open webcam for real-time prediction
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open webcam.")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        break

    # Convert the frame from BGR (OpenCV) to RGB (PIL)
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Convert NumPy array to PIL Image
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame_rgb)

    # Preprocess the frame
    input_image = preprocess(pil_image)  # Use the PIL image for preprocessing
    input_image = input_image.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

    # Predict using the model
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_image)
        
        # Apply softmax to get probabilities
        probabilities = torch.softmax(outputs, dim=1)
        
        # Get the predicted class and confidence
        _, predicted = torch.max(probabilities, 1)
        confidence = probabilities[0][predicted].item() * 100  # Convert to percentage
        label = class_names[predicted.item()]

    # Display the result with confidence level
    cv2.putText(frame, f"Predicted: {label}, Confidence: {confidence:.2f}%", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Sign Detection", frame)

    # Exit on pressing 'q'
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

the confidence levels are always high but with the wrong labels, even if I show on the webcam 5 fingers it's stuck on zero.
I feel like the problem is with the frame processing, does anyone have any insight on this?

Make sure to use real world data during training. Make sure to use the same preprocessing (image normalization, channel ordering, etc.) during training and  prediction. Verify with sone offline samples that both implementations (training code and project code) predict the same results and confidence score values.

Oops, my bad...

This issue mainly results from how class labels are encoded and loaded during training. Ensure that the labels are encoded and loaded the same way as you did during training so that the indexing is not messed up, that is if the classes are sorted during training make sure they are also sorted during inference. I hope this helps.
